# Segmenting image of multiple cells and splitting into single cells

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

Say I have this image:
[image: Image of multiple cells]

Which can be obtained via

```
from skimage.data import human_mitosis
image = human_mitosis()
```

I want to turn this image of multiple cells into multiple images for each individual cell through automatically cropping each single cell into its own image (ideally the size of the cropping is the same size/shape for each cell). So, for example, these would be some of the expected images:

[image] [image]

Although scikit has some code for segmenting cells, how do you use this segmentation (or some other potentially easier method) to separate single cells into their own images or objects?

Here is some code for segmenting the cells (taken from scikit's tutorial with this image https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_human_mitosis.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-human-mitosis-py):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage import (
    color, feature, filters, measure, morphology, segmentation, util
)

thresholds = filters.threshold_multiotsu(image, classes=3)
cells = image > thresholds[0]

distance = ndi.distance_transform_edt(cells)

local_max_coords = feature.peak_local_max(distance, min_distance=7)
local_max_mask = np.zeros(distance.shape, dtype=bool)
local_max_mask[tuple(local_max_coords.T)] = True
markers = measure.label(local_max_mask)

segmented_cells = segmentation.watershed(-distance, markers, mask=cells)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 5))
ax[0].imshow(cells, cmap='gray')
ax[0].set_title('Overlapping nuclei')
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[1].imshow(color.label2rgb(segmented_cells, bg_label=0))
ax[1].set_title('Segmented nuclei')
ax[1].axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: OpenCV provides functions to find individual cells that can be saved later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops) for this:

```py
props = measure.regionprops(
        segmented_cells, intensity_image=image
        )
```

Now `props[i].image_intensity` will contain the image of the ith cell, and `props[i].label` will contain the label value in the segmented image of that cell. You can see other properties available in the regionprops docstring.

**Edit:** An earlier version of this answer said `props[i].image` contained the cropped image. It in fact contains only the boolean mask corresponding to the region.

Comment: Thanks! Right now props[i].image returns a yellow/purple image (yellow where a cell is and purple where there isn't). Is there a way to make props[i].image have the same colors/contrast as the original image? Also, is there a way to make props in a way that each props[i].image has the same shape?

Comment: Oh, apologies, it should be `props[i].image_intensity`! Updating the answer now.